# Latex overleaf error that I can't seem to solve

Tags: latex, overleaf

I'm working on my master's thesis, in which in want to use Overleaf Latex. I have some small experience in using Overleaf Latex, so I started by creating a new project and used a preamble one of my old colleagues had created for a prior project. For some reason I'm getting an error that I can't figure out how to solve.

The error is this:

```
Package nameref Warning: The definition of \label has changed! Check your packages! 
Replacing it with the kernel definition on input line 145.
```

And this error:

```
<*> preamble_ida.tex
                    
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 24208 strings out of 475237
 427272 string characters out of 5764570
 1917244 words of memory out of 5000000
 45183 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 559543 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1143 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 79i,1n,117p,388b,265s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I guess it has something to do with the packages in the preamble.tex file? but i have no idea. I hoped someone with more experience could help me solve this so i can start my actual work.

My preamble file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,oneside,openright]{memoir}    % Openright aabner kapitler paa hoejresider (openany = vilkaarlig/begge

%%%% PAKKER %%%%

\usepackage{rotating}
% ¤¤ Oversaettelse og tegnsaetning ¤¤ %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 % Input-indkodning af tegnsaet, dvs. input fra keyboard, tegnoversigt eller andet (UTF8 = Unicode)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % Output-indkodning af tegnsaet, dvs. printede fonte og tegn (T1 = Type 1 font med support for de fleste europaeiske sprog)
\usepackage[danish]{babel}                  % Sproglig fremstilling af elementer (figur vs. figure, litteratur vs. bibliography osv.)
\usepackage{ragged2e,anyfontsize}           % Justering af elementer
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{ulem}

%\usepackage{lmodern}

%\usepackage{minted}

% ¤¤ Figurer og tabeller (floats) ¤¤ %
\usepackage{graphicx}                       % Inkludering af eksterne billeder (JPG, PNG, PDF)
\usepackage{multirow}                       % Fletning af raekker og kolonner (\multicolumn og \multirow)
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{colortbl}                       % Farver i tabeller (fx \columncolor, \rowcolor og \cellcolor)
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}             % Definer farver med \definecolor. Se mere: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors
\usepackage{flafter}                        % Soerger for, at floats ikke optraeder i teksten foer deres reference
\usepackage{float}                          % Muliggoer eksakt placering af floats, fx \begin{figure}[H]
\let\newfloat\relax                         % Justering mellem float-pakken og memoir
%\usepackage{eso-pic}                       % Tilfoej billedekommandoer paa hver side
%\usepackage{wrapfig}                       % Indsaettelse af figurer omsvoebt af tekst 
%\usepackage{multicol}                      % Muliggoer tekst i spalter
%\usepackage{rotating}                      % Rotation af tekst med \begin{sideways}...\end{sideways}

% ¤¤ Matematik mm. ¤¤
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       % Avancerede matematik-udvidelser
\usepackage{mathtools}                      % Andre matematik- og tegnudvidelser
\usepackage{textcomp}                       % Symbol-udvidelser (fx promille-tegn med \textperthousand)
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % Flot og konsistent praesentation af tal og enheder med \si{enhed} og \SI{tal}{enhed}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}       % Opsaetning af \SI og decimalseparator
%\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}             % Kemi-pakke til flot og let notation af formler, fx \ce{Fe2O3}
%\usepackage{rsphrase}                      % Kemi-pakke til RS-saetninger, fx \rsphrase{R1}

% ¤¤ Referencer og kilder ¤¤ %
\usepackage[danish]{varioref}               % Muliggoer bl.a. krydshenvisninger med sidetal (\vref)
\usepackage{natbib}                         % Udvidelse med naturvidenskabelige citationsmodeller, herunder Harvard-modellen
%\usepackage{xr}                            % Referencer til eksternt dokument med \externaldocument{<NAVN>}
%\usepackage{glossaries}                    % Terminologi- eller symbolliste (se mere i Lars Madsens Latex-bog)
% ¤¤ Misc. ¤¤ %
\usepackage{listings}                       % Placer kildekode i dokumentet med \begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{lipsum}                         % Dummy tekst med fx \lipsum[2]
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}          % Muliggoer enkelt konfiguration af lister (se \setlist nedenfor)
\usepackage{pdfpages}                       % Goer det muligt at inkludere pdf-dokumenter med kommandoen \includepdf[pages={x-y}]{fil.pdf}  
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6                 % Muliggoer inkludering af pdf-dokumenter af version 1.6 og hoejere
\pretolerance=2500                          % Justering af afstand mellem ord (hoejt tal, mindre orddeling og mere luft mellem ord)

% Kommentarer og rettelser med \fxnote. Med 'final' i stedet for 'draft' udloeser hver note en error i den faerdige rapport.
\usepackage[footnote,draft,danish,silent,nomargin]{fixme}       


%%%% BRUGERDEFINEREDE INDSTILLINGER %%%%

% ¤¤ Marginer ¤¤ %
\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}      % \setlrmarginsandblock{Indbinding}{Kant}{Ratio}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3.0cm}{*}      % \setulmarginsandblock{Top}{Bund}{Ratio}
\checkandfixthelayout                       % Oversaetter vaerdier til brug for andre pakker

%   ¤¤ Afsnitsformatering ¤¤ %
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}                 % Stoerrelse af indryk
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}                   % Afstand mellem afsnit ved brug af double Enter
\linespread{1,1}                            % Linjeafstand

% ¤¤ Litteraturlisten ¤¤ %
\bibpunct[,]{[}{]}{;}{a}{,}{,}              % Definerer parametre ved Harvard-henvisning (bl.a. parantestype og seperatortegn)
\bibliographystyle{bibtex/harvard}          % Udseende af litteraturlisten (Harvard-metoden - skift til fx 'plain' for tal)

% ¤¤ Dybde af overskrifter ¤¤ %
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}                 % Dybden af nummerede overkrifter (part/chapter/section/subsection)
\settocdepth{subsection}                    % Dybden af overskrifter vist i indholdsfortegnelsen

% ¤¤ Lister ¤¤ %
\setlist{
  topsep=0pt,                               % Vertikal afstand mellem tekst og listen
  itemsep=-1ex,                             % Vertikal afstand mellem items
} 

% ¤¤ Visuelle referencer ¤¤ %
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}           % Danner klikbare referencer (hyperlinks) i dokumentet
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,              % Opsaetning af farvede hyperlinks (interne links, citeringer og URL)
    linkcolor = black,
    citecolor = black,
    urlcolor = black
}

% ¤¤ Opsaetning af figur- og tabeltekst ¤¤ %
\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries\itshape}   % Opsaetning af tekstdelen ('Figur' eller 'Tabel')
\captiontitlefont{\small}                   % Opsaetning af nummerering
\captiondelim{. }                           % Seperator mellem nummerering og figurtekst
\captionstyle{\centering}                   % Justering/placering af figurteksten (centreret = \centering, venstrejusteret = \raggedright)
\captionwidth{\linewidth}                   % Bredden af figurteksten
\hangcaption                                % Venstrejusterer fler-linjers figurtekst under hinanden
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}          % Afstand under figurteksten
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}

% ¤¤ Opsaetning af listings ¤¤ %
\definecolor{commentGreen}{RGB}{34,139,24}
\definecolor{stringPurple}{RGB}{208,76,239}

\lstset{language=Matlab,                    % Sprog
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,        % Opsaetning af teksten
    keywords={for,if,while,else,elseif,     % Noegleord at fremhaeve
              end,break,return,case,
              switch,function},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},              % Opsaetning af noegleord
    commentstyle=\color{commentGreen},      % Opsaetning af kommentarer
    stringstyle=\color{stringPurple},       % Opsaetning af strenge
    showstringspaces=false,                 % Mellemrum i strenge enten vist eller blanke
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,        % Linjenumre
    extendedchars=true,                     % Tillader specielle karakterer
    columns=flexible,                       % Kolonnejustering
    breaklines, breakatwhitespace=true,     % Bryd lange linjer
}

%% DETTE HAR VI SELV INDSAT %%
\definecolor{bluekeywords}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.95}
\definecolor{greencomments}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{redstrings}{rgb}{0.64,0.08,0.08}
\definecolor{xmlcomments}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{types}{rgb}{0.17,0.57,0.68}

\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
captionpos=b,
%numbers=left, %Nummerierung
%numberstyle=\tiny, % kleine Zeilennummern
frame=l, % Oberhalb und unterhalb des Listings ist eine Linie
showspaces=false,
showtabs=false,
breaklines=true,
showstringspaces=false,
breakatwhitespace=true,
escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
commentstyle=\color{greencomments},
morekeywords={partial, var, value, get, set},
keywordstyle=\color{bluekeywords},
stringstyle=\color{redstrings},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
   backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}
}

% ¤¤ Navngivning ¤¤ %
\addto\captionsdanish{
    \renewcommand\contentsname{Indholdsfortegnelse}         % Skriver 'Indholdsfortegnelse' i stedet for 'Indhold'
    \renewcommand\appendixname{Appendiks}                   % Skriver 'Appendiks' i stedet for 'Appendix'
    \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendiks}
    \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendiks}
    \renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}             % Skriver 'Kapitel' foran kapitlerne i indholdsfortegnelsen
    \renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}           % Skriver 'Appendiks' foran appendiks i indholdsfortegnelsen
}

% ¤¤ Kapiteludssende ¤¤ %
\definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.7}        % Definerer en farve til brug til kapiteludseende
\newif\ifchapternonum

\makechapterstyle{jenor}{                   % Definerer kapiteludseende frem til ...
  \renewcommand\beforechapskip{0pt}
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\chapternonumtrue}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{db}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{25}{35}\selectfont\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{1in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \noindent
    \ifchapternonum
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    {\let\\\newline\chaptitlefont ##1\par} 
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip-2.5mm\hrule
    \else
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
    {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} & \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip2mm\hrule
    \fi
  }
}                                           % ... her

\chapterstyle{jenor}                        % Valg af kapiteludseende - Google 'memoir chapter styles' for alternativer

% ¤¤ Sidehoved/sidefod ¤¤ %

\makepagestyle{Uni}                         % Definerer sidehoved og sidefod udseende frem til ...
\makepsmarks{Uni}{%
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\nouppercaseheads                                           % Ingen Caps oenskes

\makeevenhead{Uni}{Group }{}{\leftmark}             % Lige siders sidehoved (\makeevenhead{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeoddhead{Uni}{\rightmark}{}{Aalborg University}         % Ulige siders sidehoved (\makeoddhead{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeevenfoot{Uni}{\thepage}{}{}                            % Lige siders sidefod (\makeevenfoot{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeoddfoot{Uni}{}{}{\thepage}                             % Ulige siders sidefod (\makeoddfoot{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeheadrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}                       % Tilfoejer en streg under sidehovedets indhold
\makefootrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}{1mm}                  % Tilfoejer en streg under sidefodens indhold

\copypagestyle{Unichap}{Uni}                                % Der dannes en ny style til kapitelsider
\makeoddhead{Unichap}{}{}{}                                 % Sidehoved defineres som blank på kapitelsider
\makeevenhead{Unichap}{}{}{}
\makeheadrule{Unichap}{\textwidth}{0pt}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{Unichap}                           % Den ny style vaelges til at gaelde for chapters
                                                            % ... her
\pagestyle{Uni}                                             % Valg af sidehoved og sidefod (benyt 'plain' for ingen sidehoved/fod)


%%%% EGNE KOMMANDOER %%%%

% ¤¤ Billede hack ¤¤ %                                      % Indsaet figurer nemt med \figur{Stoerrelse}{Fil}{Figurtekst}{Label}
\newcommand{\figur}[4]{
        \begin{figure}[H] \centering
            \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{billeder/#2}
            \caption{#3}
            \label{#4}
        \end{figure} 
}

% ¤¤ Specielle tegn ¤¤ %
\newcommand{\dec}{^{\circ}}                                 % '\dec' returnerer et gradtegn (husk $$ udenfor aligns)
\newcommand{\decC}{^{\circ}\text{C}}                        % '\decC' returnerer et gradtegn + 'C' (husk $$ udenfor aligns)
\newcommand{\m}{\cdot}                                      % '\m' returnerer et gangetegn

%%%% ORDDELING %%%%
\hyphenation{In-te-res-se e-le-ment}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: Please ask Latex questions on [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).